# How to make grep to work with newline in bash variable

Tags: bash, ubuntu, grep

I want to use `grep` to filter some lines defined in a bash variable.

**If the variable is defined within the "`$(cat)`", then the result is **correct**:**

```
test_string=$(cat <<END
hello
world
test
bar hello
END
)

echo -e "$test_string"

filter_string="$(grep "hello" <<< "$test_string")"

echo -e "$filter_string"
```

**Here is the correct output:**

```
# test_string=$(cat <<END
hello
world
test
bar hello
END
)
# echo -e "$test_string"
hello
world
test
bar hello
# filter_string="$(grep "hello" <<< "$test_string")"
# echo -e "$filter_string"
hello
bar hello
#
```

**But if defined the variable with "`\n`" (use script to join many other strings into a single multiple lines variable), the grep will not work as expected:**

```
test_string="hello\nworld\ntest\nbar hello"

echo -e "$test_string"

filter_string="$(grep "hello" <<< "$test_string")"

echo -e "$filter_string"
```

**Here is the wrong output:**

```
# test_string="hello\nworld\ntest\nbar hello"
# echo -e "$test_string"
hello
world
test
bar hello
# filter_string="$(grep "hello" <<< "$test_string")"
# echo -e "$filter_string"
hello
world
test
bar hello
#
```

How to make `grep` find command to work with "`\n`" in variable?

**Update:**

**Here is the code for creating the multiple lines variable:**

```
test_string="hello"
test_string="${test_string}\nworld"
test_string="${test_string}\ntest"
test_string="${test_string}\nbar hello"
```

**The content of `test_string` is dynamical by joining other words from other source.**

**Update 2: Join two string variables with "\n":**

```
other_string="world"

test_string="hello"
test_string+=$'\n${other_string}'
test_string+=$'\ntest'
test_string+=$'\nbar hello'

echo "$test_string"
```

**Here is the output:**

```
hello
${other_string}
test
bar hello
```

Comment: Stop using `echo -e`. It doesn't print your string's exact content but instead the result of processing it (and whether it works at all is extremely dependent on your shell's current configuration; sometimes it prints `-e` as part of its output). Use `declare -p test_string` to get an unambiguous printout of content in bash, or `printf '%s\n' "$test_string"` to write the literal content to stdout without any transformation.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113 for a full writeup on just how unreliable `echo` is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you declare a variable as `test_string="hello\nworld\ntest\nbar hello"` it stored literal `\n` in the declare variable instead of line breaks.

Use `printf` to declare a variable with `\n` embedded like this:

```bash
printf -v test_string '%b\n' "hello\nworld\ntest\nbar hello"
```

Or else use `$'...'` directive like this in `bash`:

```bash
test_string=$'hello\nworld\ntest\nbar hello'
```

Then use `grep`:

```bash
filter_string="$(grep "hello" <<< "$test_string")"

# check variable content
declare -p filter_string
```

**Output:**

```bash
declare -- filter_string="hello
bar hello"
```

---

Updated answer:

```bash
test_string="hello"
test_string+=$'\nworld'
test_string+=$'\ntest'
test_string+=$'\nbar hello'

echo "$test_string"

echo '---- output ---'
filter_string="$(grep "hello" <<< "$test_string")"
# check variable content
echo "$filter_string"
```

**Output:**

```bash
hello
world
test
bar hello
---- output ---
hello
bar hello
```

Comment: Can you help to explain how to generate the multiple lines variable by bash code? I have update the post for using the original "\n" method to create the variable. Please check. Thanks.

Comment: check my updated answer for that.

Comment: When the string to append is a variabele, use `test_string+=$'\n'"${next_part}"`

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
test_string="
hello
world
test
bar hello
"

$ grep hello <<< $test_string 
hello
bar hello
```